# Import error on EMR after bootstrap action

Tags: numpy, pyspark, pip, amazon-emr

I'm running a bootstrap action on an EMR cluster and I'm checking the numpy version after I run through requirements text file with:

```
sudo python3 -c "try:
    import numpy
    print(\"numpy_version\", numpy.version.version)
except:
    pass"
```

I'm getting the correct version specified in the requirements text file (1.15.4); however, after the job starts running, i get:

```
ImportError: Matplotlib requires numpy>=1.15; you have 1.14.5
```

What exactly is happening in between the bootstrap action and the job steps that is reverting the version of numpy?

Comment: Can you see the output of `pyspark`? is it running python3?

Comment: That is the output of pyspark and it's running python3. Basically, if i import numpy in pyspark, it reverts to the old version. It's almost like something on Amazon's end is installing an old version of numpy.

Comment: isnt it the output of spark-submit, can you please write pyspark in console and let me know what version it prints, how you know that spark is actually running python3?

Comment: the bootstrap runs before application provisioning, the application provisioning downgrade the numpy's version

Comment: I would say run a background process as a bootstrap action to upgrade numpy after the provisioning then exit

Comment: @A.B My PYSPARK_PYTHON property is set to python3 under configurations in the EMR console.

Comment: @AbdelrahmanMaharek I thought the point of a bootstrap action was to configure the stock EMR environment of each node after provisioning.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-plan-bootstrap.html  "Bootstrap actions are scripts that run on cluster after Amazon EMR launches the instance using the Amazon Linux Amazon Machine Image (AMI). Bootstrap actions run before Amazon EMR installs the applications that you specify when you create the cluster and before cluster nodes begin processing data."

Answer (score 0):

This indicates that the application provisioning downgrades the numpy's version

A workaround for this issue is by using a bootstrap action which launches another background process.

The background process should upgrades numpy's version and should run right after the application provisioning.